# What are the pizza delivery guys called?

Tags: words, word-requests

I was thinking of the word ピザ配達者, or ピザ人、but it doesn't read right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most definitely *not* ピザ人, unless you are thinking of a person from [Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisa) (though I think that they are technically イタリア人.)

I went to dominos.jp and found the following:

[image: Dominos.jp online orders]

Obviously, 配達｛はいたつ｝ is the word for delivery that is used in connection with pizza.  At that point a [simple dictionary lookup for 配達](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%85%8D%E9%81%94) showed that [配達人｛はいたつにん｝](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%85%8D%E9%81%94%E4%BA%BA) is the word that you are looking for.

配達者 returned no results in the dictionary.

Comment: Is the word pizza needed?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's similar to that the English formation in that you can add it, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Google ピザ配達人 and see what you get.

Comment: thats the correct one

Comment: @JACK  You can refer to the delivery man both with and without the ピザ attached. I wouldn't be surprised if the Japanese people left it off frequently in situations where it is mutually understood what 配達人 you are talking about.